# Series command no longer expands arbitrary functions after aborting previous evaluation

Tags: series-expansion

I asked Mathematica 9 to execute the `SeriesCoefficient` command on a rather horrendously complicated expression. After some time I decided to abort the evaluation and try something different.

Somehow, this has caused the `Series` and `SeriesCoefficient` commands to stop working properly. They can still correctly expand known functions, for example things like `Series[x^2*BesselJ[Sin[x],x],{x,0,5}]` do work as expected, but for arbitrary, not-yet-defined functions they no longer work, so `Series[f[x],{x,0,2}]` now returns just `f[x]` rather than the expected `f[0]+f'[0]x+f''[0]x^2/2+O[x]^3`.

Does anyone know what exactly might have caused this and how I could fix it without having to restart the kernel? (Presumably the previous call to `SeriesCoefficient` changed some obscure internal parameter in the kernel which may be reversible...)

I have a bunch of long, precalculated expressions in the kernel's memory and it would be quite annoying to have to export all of them and reimport into a new kernel.

Comment: Do you have an example of a function that takes "horrendously" long to generate the series? Likely a restart is required, though.

Comment: @rcollyer These are terms in asymptotic expansions of a curvature tensor in high dimensions, some of them are many hundreds of lines long and take hours to extract. Unfortunately I don't think I can reasonably paste the code which will duplicate my expressions in this space. I understand that I'm not making it easy for people to reproduce this condition, but I thought there might be some attribute which causes Series to avoid processing arbitrary functions.

Comment: None that I can think of. What's your memory usage?

Comment: MathKernel is using just over 580MB. My system still has just under 4GB available though.

Comment: You could put such an expression in any [pastebin](http://pastie.org) that allows accessing the raw paste data through a link.  Then people can `Import` from that link and test that way.

Comment: I've underestimated my expression. The culprit seems to be over 20000 lines long and I couldn't find a pastebin that wouldn't choke on it. If anyone's interested I've [uploaded it](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1909695/MetricFG13) in the form which can be quickly imported using `MetricFG13=(<<"MetricFG13");`. The command which caused the problem was `SeriesCoefficient[MetricFG13,{\[Xi],0,4}]`. (I think I let it run for something like 20 minutes before aborting.)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's absolutely impossible to give a specific answer, so I can only remark that `SeriesCoefficient` works differently in version 9. For a *list* or *array* of functions, version 8 does *not* evaluate expressions like this:

```
SeriesCoefficient[{f[x], h[x]}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

but version 9 *does*. Maybe this causes problems somewhere in your expression. But really, I have no idea how else to track down your issue than to go through the list of incompatibilities between the versions one by one. This is the first that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks, but I highly doubt it's related to that. I'm not trying to expand array of expressions, plus, both `Series` and `SeriesCoefficient` worked fine until now. (And they still do if I start fresh kernels). I guess there's not much I can do at this point other than restart and hope it doesn't occur again.